# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/4admin/apache/vhosts/

Tags: php

Anyone know why I am getting the following error message?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /usr/local/4admin/apache/vhosts/abmhd.com/httpdocs/Forms/Email.php on line 11  " Line 11 is " $recipient = "Me@mywebsite.com "

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website:           $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "Me@mywebsite.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var     s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a) {s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2) {c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>`
```

Comment: Escape the double quotes in $recipient var

Comment: Having a quick look at your question's colouration should give you an hint ;)

Comment: $formcontent is missing a closing quote.

Comment: @j08691 It's in there, just tucked way over to the right `...\n Message: $message";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, I didn't scroll!

Comment: @j08691 I never was much of a fan for "left to right" scrolling in web browsers myself ;-) very very old school stuff in web design LOL! To think they used to call it "creative".

Answer (score 1):

You should escape like this:

```
$recipient = "Me@mywebsite.com<script type=\"text/javascript\">
```

And the same for all " inside the variable definition.

Or maybe easier to change the outer double apostrophes to single ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotation marks for the  tags (and also again inside the js code):

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website:           $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "Me@mywebsite.com<script type=\"text/javascript\">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var     s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName(\"script\");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a) {s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2) {c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Also, it's good practice to wrap your variables with {} inside quotation marks.

Comment: Hey guys; I tried each and all suggestions... nothing worked ! I would appreciate any other way that you might think of.